# How to avoid the duplicate values in dropdown field in dynamically generated rows

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, symfony, twig

I am using macros in my twig to achieve the dynamically adding rows functionality the macro part of it is as follows:

```
{% macro macroLeave(item, hrisFlag) %}
            <tr>
                <td width="28%"  align="left" height="30" bgcolor="#f6f6f6">
                    {{ form_widget(item.leaveType) }}
                    {{ form_errors(item.leaveType) }} 
                </td>
            </tr>
{% endmacro %}
```

necessary javascript snippets is given below:

```
var addLeaveRow = function() 
        {
            var index = $('#tblLeave tbody tr').length;
            var row = $('script[name="scriptLeave"]').text().replace(/\$\$name\$\$/g, index);
            $('#tblLeave tbody').append(row);
        }
```

Can anybody suggest a way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
// keep track of the id's 'name of leave' that must be unique.
var allLeaves = {};

// ... before you add it, check if it exists.
if (typeof(allLeaves['name of leave']) === "undefined") {
    allleaves['name of leave'] = true;
    // ... now do your stuff.
} else {
    // the leave already exists, so perhaps focus it for the user?
}
```